# What set do generic types define?

Tags: group-theory, logic, model-theory

Let $G$ be an infinite $\omega$-stable group and $p \in S(G)$ a generic type. What set does $p$ define? Or do we know anything about it? Like where it lies.

I am struggling with generic types/planes/etc in model theory. It would be also great if someone could suggest me some sources about it to read.

Comment: "I am struggling with generic types/planes/etc in model theory." Where did you come across the notion of a "generic plane" in model theory?

Comment: Well it was actually an example in a model theory paper "The indiscernible topology: a mock Zariski topology" . In the example a generic plane defined by a formula in $K^3$ is considered. So I am thinking maybe it just means that the plane has Morley rank 3 and lies in one of the irreducible components of $K^3$.

Comment: That's a reasonable guess: a plane is a definable set in $K^3$, and we sometimes say that a definable set is generic if it has full Morley rank. But it can't be right: Assuming $K$ is an algebraically closed field, $K^3$ has Morley rank $3$ and degree $1$ (so it has only one irreducible component), but any plane has Morley rank $2$. So no plane can be generic in that sense.

Comment: Instead, what the authors mean is this: Any plane in $K^3$ is defined by an equation $ax + by + cz + d = 0$. Thus the family of all planes in $K^3$ forms a family of definable sets, parametrized by all tuples $(a,b,c,d)\in K^4$. Then a "generic plane" is a plane parametrized by a generic tuple, i.e. a tuple $(a,b,c,d)$ realizing the generic type in $K^4$. This means that the tuple $(a,b,c,d)$ is algebraically independent over $K^4$.

Comment: I had a look at the paper, and the authors write in the next line "Let $\alpha_0$, $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$ be algebraically independent elements such that $P$ is given by the equation $x_3 = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1x_2 + \alpha_2x_2$." You can take this as the definition of "generic plane" - this is the same as what I wrote above, because e.g. $a\neq 0$, so the tuple $(1,b/a,c/a,d/a)$ defines the same plane as $(a,b,c,d)$, and if $(a,b,c,d)$ are algebraically independent, so are $(b/a,c/a,d/a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any $\omega$-stable theory $T$, the formula $\top$ or $x = x$ in the context of a single free variable $x$ has a Morley rank $\alpha$ (an ordinal) and a Morley degree $n$ (a natural number). The degree $n$ is the maximal number of pairwise disjoint definable sets of Morley rank $\alpha$. Working in a sufficiently saturated model $M\models T$, $M$ is partitioned into $n$ definable pieces $X_1,\dots,X_n$, each of Morley rank $\alpha$, and this partition is unique up to adjustments by definable sets of rank $<\alpha$. We call the pieces of the partition *irreducible components* of $M$.

Now a type $p\in S_1(M)$ is *generic* if it has Morley rank $\alpha$. Since the $X_i$ form a partition, $p$ must live in in one of the sets $X_i$. But for every definable subset $Y\subseteq X_i$, either $Y$ or $X_i\setminus Y$ has rank $<\alpha$ (otherwise we could split $X_i$ into two pieces of full rank and get a bigger partition). So since $p$ does not live in any definable set of rank $<\alpha$, $p$ is uniquely determined by which irreducible component $X_i$ it lives in. So $S_1(M)$ contains exactly $n$ generic types.

To your question "where does a generic type lie", the answer is...well, almost everywhere!  (In its irreducible component.) A realization of a generic type $p\in S_1(M)$ (in an elementary extension of $M$) lives in the irreducible component $X$ of $p$, but not in any "small" (in the sense of rank) $M$-definable subset of $X$. So $p$ defines the set of elements of $X$ which do not lie in any lower-rank $M$-definable subset of $X$.

If you know something about algebraic geometry, a good analogy is that the generic types in an $\omega$-stable theory are like the generic points of irreducible components of an algebraic variety. The Zariski closure of a generic point is its entire irreducible component, because it does not live in any proper Zariski closed subset.

All of the above was in the general context of $\omega$-stable theories. Specializing to $\omega$-stable groups, we get some additional information about generic types. Let $G$ be a sufficiently saturated $\omega$-stable group.

- $G$ has a "connected component of the identity" $G^0$, which is the minimal definable subgroup of finite index in $G$. The Morley degree is the index of this subgroup and the irreducible components are its cosets. So there is exactly one generic type living in each coset of $G^0$.
- A definable subset $X\subseteq G$ has full rank $\alpha$ if and only if finitely many translates of $X$ cover $G$, i.e. $a_1\cdot X \cup \dots \cup a_n\cdot X = {G}$ for some $a_1,\dots,a_n\in {G}$. So a generic type only contains formulas defining "wide" sets in the sense that finitely many translates cover the group. This is a precise sense in which  "where a generic type lives" can't be pinned down very tightly.
- Any element of $G$ is a product of two generic elements over $G$, i.e. for all $g\in G$ there exist $a,b\in \mathbb{G}$, a sufficiently saturated elementary extension of $G$, such that $a\cdot b = g$ and $\text{tp}(a/G)$ and $\text{tp}(b/G)$ are generic.

For your reference request: If you are particularly interested in $\omega$-stable theories and $\omega$-stable groups, Marker's book *Model Theory: An Introduction* gives a good overview (Chapters 6 and 7 - all the facts I wrote above are proven there). $\omega$-stability is a special case of the more general theory of stability. For more information on stable groups in general, the standard reference is Poizat's book *Stable Groups*. For stable theories in general, there are many references. Which one is best for you depends on your background and interests.

Comment: That was a really clear and helping answer, thank you!